# How to search in a large table with AES_DECRYPT?

Tags: mysql

I store sensitive data in a mysql table with **AES_DECRYPT**. Right now the table is about 50 Mb.

I have had a web interface (with php) where the visitors can search for data. I performed a LIKE search:

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(content,'salt') FROM table
WHERE CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(content,'salt') USING utf8) LIKE '%search%'
```

It works fine, but it has become very very slow. Do you have any ideas how to combine good security and a good search function?

Comment: What security benefit do you perceive you are achieving through using encryption functions in this way? RDBMS and application have access to both keys and plaintext when in transit, so the only benefit is at rest, on disk. Even then, if that disk also contains your application code then it holds the decryption keys (and it may do so even if not - e.g. in SQL logs): so you've probably only achieved [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) - pretty pointless. And of course it's slow: indexes cannot be used, so MySQL must perform full table scans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL can not search efficiently on columns, which are wrapped in functions. One can not create indexes on function evaluations in MySQL, like it is possible with PostgreSQL.

Since the needed keys to decrypt the content must be provided to MySQL for this type of query, I do not see a reason, why the database server should encrypt the contents. From a security perspective the AES encryption is useless at this point of stage. The key is in the memory of the process and thus the data is theoretically not secure anymore. (If an attacker can take over the memory of the process, he has key and data => not secure).

If one follows this view, it makes no sense to use the `AES` functions of MySQL in this way. If you want to proceed this way nevertheless, you must save unencrypted data somewhere for MySQL being able to index it.

To protect the data from outsiders, it may make sense to encrypt the storage of MySQL instead. This can be (more or less) easily achieved by just setting up an encrypted volume und moving the data dir of MySQL to this location. (See for example this [Ubuntu Tutorial for encrypted filesystems](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemHowto).) For performance reasons one should only move those files, which contain sensitive information.

This is a more easy solution, but bears some performance and administration risks. There is [a question](https://serverfault.com/questions/191459/disk-encryption-in-debian) on serverfault, which answers you might want to read.